# i am unable to run cucumber jvm test in selenium grid in parallel

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, grid, cucumber-jvm

I am testing cucumber jvm with Test NG XML for selenium grid parallel execution on both firefox and chrome.

In TestNG XML,i have given class file as Cucumber `runner.java` file and this java file contains the path of my features.

When I ran my `testNg.xml`, I am not getting any response and i can see blank test NG reports.

> **Note:** i tried the same script in Junit cucumber in grid for chrome and working fine.

Added annotation `@parameter("BrowserName")` on test `case.java` file which need to be tested on both chrome and firefox.

TestNG.xml

```
<!-- package name Test1,Cucumber runner file name= runner>

<suite name="Test1" verbose="3"  parallel="tests" thread-count="2">   
  <test name="Run on Firefox">
    <parameter name="browserName"  value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="Test1.runner"/>
    </classes>
 </test>  
  <test name="Run on chrome">
    <classes>
    <parameter name="browserName"  value="chrome"/>
      <class name="Test1.runner"/>
    </classes>
 </test>
 </suite>
```

and please tell me the details steps to integrate with jenkin. Jenkins integrate with cucumber jvm for grid -parallel testing.

My last question, I am new to grid, i would like to know that we can see all the browsers running on multiple node or we cant see any thing other than results when running via Jenkins.

Thanks,
Senthil

Comment: Try generic cucumber runner explained in detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41100104/2895913).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put '' tag above '' in Chrome section.

Secondly, to execute your tests through Jenkins you can use following link: http://moduscreate.com/integrating-bdd-cucumber-test-suites-jenkins-3-steps/

Thirdly, to view the browsers/instances running on Grid, navigate to following URL on hub machine 'http://localhost:4444/console' and further click on 'Console' link. You will be able to see all the nodes connected to Hub and also the different instances running on nodes..