# How to execute cucumber feature file parallel

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm

I have below feature files (Separate feature files) in src/test/resources/feature/ and I would like to run them in parallel. Like: One feature file has to execute in chrome and another one has to execute in firefox as mentioned @Tags name.

```
Feature: Refund item

@chrome
  Scenario: Jeff returns a faulty microwave
    Given Jeff has bought a microwave for $100
    And he has a receipt
    When he returns the microwave
    Then Jeff should be refunded $100

Feature: Refund Money

@firefox
  Scenario: Jeff returns the money
    Given Jeff has bought a microwave for $100
    And he has a receipt
    When he returns the microwave
    Then Jeff should be refunded $100
```

Can somebody assist me to achieve this.I'm using cucumber-java 1.2.2 version, and AbstractTestNGCucumberTests using as runner.  Also, let me know how can I create a Test Runner dynamically by using feature files and make them run in parallel.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? What is the end goal?

Comment: I would like to execute the feature files in parallel with different browsers. I have a application where i need to do browser compatibility testing. So far we had sequence execution to validate the browser compatibility. I just heard about cucumber-jvm-parallel plugin but not much aware how to implement it. And heard that It will create a runners in dynamically and help us to do parallel execution in scenario or feature wise.

Comment: You can try maven and surefire plugin. It will use multiple threads which will run each available runner individually. Google cucmber java maven parallel. Used to have the link for the article but somehow got deleted

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update:**  4.0.0 version is available at maven central repository with bunch of changes.[for more details go here.](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin)

**Update:**  2.2.0 version is available at maven central repository.

You can use opensource plugin [cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin) which has many advantages over existing solutions. Available at maven [repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin)

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

1. First you need to add this plugin with required configuration in your project pom file.

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>generateRunners</id>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generateRunners</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Mandatory -->
            <!-- comma separated list of package names to scan for glue code -->
            <glue>foo, bar</glue>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
             <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
              <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features/</featuresDirectory>
             <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
             <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
             <!-- comma separated list of output formats json,html,rerun.txt -->
             <format>json</format>
             <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
             <strict>true</strict>
             <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
             <monochrome>true</monochrome>
             <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property you can pass ANDed tags like "@tag1","@tag2" and ORed tags like "@tag1,@tag2,@tag3" -->
            <tags></tags>
            <!-- If set to true, only feature files containing the required tags shall be generated. -->
            <filterFeaturesByTags>false</filterFeaturesByTags>
            <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of default JUnit ones. --> 
            <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
            <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' --> 
           <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
           <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
           <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
           <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
           <parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>
           <!-- This is optional, required only if you want to specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a relative path) -->
           <customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>
           </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
   ```
2. Now add below plugin just below above plugin which will invoke runner classes generated by above plugin

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.19</version>
           <configuration> 
               <forkCount>5</forkCount>
               <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
               <includes>
                   <include>**/*IT.class</include>
               </includes>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. Above two plugins will do magic for cucumber test running in parallel (provided you machine also have advanced hardware support).
4. Strictly provided  `<forkCount>n</forkCount>` here 'n' is directly proportional to 1) Advanced Hardware support and 2) you available nodes i.e. registered browser instances to HUB.
5. One major and most important changes is your WebDriver class must be **SHARED** and you should **not** implement driver.quit() method, as closing is take care by shutdown hook.

   ```
   import cucumber.api.Scenario;
   import cucumber.api.java.After;
   import cucumber.api.java.Before;
   import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;

   public class SharedDriver extends EventFiringWebDriver {
       private static WebDriver REAL_DRIVER = null;



       private static final Thread CLOSE_THREAD = new Thread() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               REAL_DRIVER.close();
           }
       };

       static {
           Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(CLOSE_THREAD);
       }

       public SharedDriver() {
           super(CreateDriver());
       }

       public static WebDriver CreateDriver() {
           WebDriver webDriver;
           if (REAL_DRIVER == null)
               webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
           setWebDriver(webDriver);
           return webDriver;
       }

       public static void setWebDriver(WebDriver webDriver) {
           this.REAL_DRIVER = webDriver;
       }

       public static WebDriver getWebDriver() {
           return this.REAL_DRIVER;
       }

       @Override
       public void close() {
           if (Thread.currentThread() != CLOSE_THREAD) {
               throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You shouldn't close this WebDriver. It's shared and will close when the JVM exits.");
           }
           super.close();
       }

       @Before
       public void deleteAllCookies() {
           manage().deleteAllCookies();
       }

       @After
       public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
           try {
               byte[] screenshot = getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
               scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
           } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
               System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Considering you want to execute more than 50 threads i.e. same no of browser instances are registered to HUB but Hub will die if it doesn't get enough memory therefore to avoid this critical situation you should start hub with -DPOOL_MAX=512 (or larger) as stated in [grid2 documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

   `Really large (>50 node) Hub installations may need to increase the jetty threads by setting -DPOOL_MAX=512 (or larger) on the java command line.`

   `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role hub -DPOOL_MAX=512`

Comment: Many thanks sugat Mankar for your inputs. Its very useful.

Comment: I don't really get. Why do I need to add `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` if it is still needed to specify forks in  `maven-surefire-plugin`?

Comment: @olyv this plugin only generate runner classes, depending on tags you passed. Execution is not purpose of this plugin and hence it is done by surefire plugin.

Comment: @SugatMankar o, makes sense to me

Comment: @SugatMankar How it differs from Cucable plugin?

Answer (score 5):

Cucumber does not support parallel execution out of the box. 
I've tried, but it is not friendly.

1. We have to use maven's capability to invoke it in parallel. Refer [link](https://opencredo.com/running-cucumber-jvm-tests-in-parallel/)
2. Also there is a github project which uses custom plugin to execute in parallel.
   Refer [cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin)

Comment: Thanks bharath kumar. It helps a lot.

Comment: This seems to be the way to collate parallel cucumber json output files into one report: https://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilder   .   Also, for Ruby, putting parallel_cucumber module in a Rakefile seems to run things in parallel without a problem.

Comment: How to generate consolidated report for Cucumber java. Because I get separate folder for each feature file like 1, 2, 3 , 4. Each will contains the js and html file. How to consolidate everything.

Comment: @Ashokkumar
You'll have to write an implementation to merge the reports. I'd suggest to generate [Cucumber JSON](https://relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/formatters/json-output-formatter) output file and have your implementation parse JSON files to generate a single report.

Comment: Parallel execution is supported natively since v4.0.0

Answer (score 3):

If all you are expecting is to be able to run multiple features in parallel, then you can try doing the following :

- Duplicate the class [AbstractTestNGCucumberTests](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/testng/src/main/java/cucumber/api/testng/AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java) in your test project and set the attribute `parallel=true` to the `@DataProvider` annotated method.

Since the default `dataprovider-thread-count` from TestNG is `10` and now that you have instructed TestNG to run `features` in parallel, you should start seeing your feature files get executed in parallel.

But I understand that Cucumber reporting is inherently not thread safe, so your reports may appear garbled.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs krishnana mahadevan.

Comment: thanks! works for me. only need to add testNG runner dependency implementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:4.0.0")

Comment: This will run Scenarios in parallel but not the feature files. How to run a feature file in parallel? means in t1 threads will run all the scenarios of one feature file in sequence, similar in t2 thread will run another feature file scenarios in a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

To take maximum advantage of TestNG you can use Testng's third party extension [QAF](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) framework. It supports multiple [bdd syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) including gherkin using [GherkinFactory](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html).
While using BDD with QAF, you can take advantage of each TestNG features, including data-providers, parallel execution configuration in different ways (groups/tests/methods), TestNG listeners.

QAF considers each scenario as TestNG test and Scenario Outline as TestNG data-driven test. As qaf provides driver management and resource management in-built, you don't need to write single line of code for driver management or resource management. All you need to do is create TestNG xml configuration file as per your requirement either to run parallel methods (scenarios) or groups or xml test on one or more browser.

It enables different possible [configuration combinations](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/creating_configuration_file.html). Below is the xml **configuration to address this question** which will run scenarios in two browsers and in parallel. You can configure number of threads for each browser as standard TestNG xml configuration as well.

```
<suite name="AUT Test Automation" verbose="0"  parallel="tests">
<test name="Test-on-chrome">
   <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="resources/features" />
   <parameter name="driver.name" value="chromeDriver" />           
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
   </classes>
</test>

<test name="Test-on-FF">
   <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="resources/features" />
   <parameter name="driver.name" value="firefoxDriver" />           
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
   </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

More over the latest `BDDTestFactory2` supports [syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html) that is derived from QAF BDD, Jbehave and gherkin. It supports meta-data from qaf bdd as tags and examples from gherkin. You can take benefit of [inbuilt data-providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) to provide test data in XML/JSON/CSV/EXCEL/DB using meta-data in BDD.

**EDIT:**
Cucumber-5 users can take benefit of [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) support library.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved cucumber parallelism using [`courgette-jvm`](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm) . It worked out of the box and run parallel test at scenario level

Simply inlclude similar runner class in cucumber. My tests are further using `RemoteWebdriver` to open multiple instances on selenium grid. Make sure grid is up and running and node is registered to the grid.

```
import courgette.api.CourgetteOptions;
import courgette.api.CourgetteRunLevel;
import courgette.api.CucumberOptions;
import courgette.api.testng.TestNGCourgette;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@Test
@CourgetteOptions(
        threads = 10,
        runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
        rerunFailedScenarios = true,
        rerunAttempts = 1,
        showTestOutput = true,
        reportTitle = "Courgette-JVM Example",
        reportTargetDir = "build",
        environmentInfo = "browser=chrome; git_branch=master",
        cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
                features = "src/test/resources/com/test/",
                glue = "com.test.stepdefs",                   
                publish = true,
                plugin = {
                        "pretty",
                        "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                        "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"}
        ))
class AcceptanceIT extends TestNGCourgette {
}
```

RemoteWebdriver config is

```
protected RemoteWebDriver createDriver() throws MalformedURLException , IOException {
                   
                 Properties properties = new Properties();                
                ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();                
                  String hubURL = "http://192.168.1.7:65299/wd/hub";
                  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/amit/Desktop/amit/projects/misc/geckodriver");
                 
                    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
                    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);    
                    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options.merge(capabilities);                 
                   driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL),options));
                   return driver.get();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since v4 of Cucumber you can do this without extensions of plugins.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-testng#parallel-execution

> Cucumber TestNG supports parallel execution of scenarios. Override the
> scenarios method to enable parallel execution.
>
> ```java
> public class RunCucumberTest extends
> AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
>
>     @Override
>     @DataProvider(parallel = true)
>     public Object[][] scenarios() {
>         return super.scenarios();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Maven Surefire plugin configuration for parallel execution
>
> ```xml
> <plugins>    <plugin>
>       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>       <configuration>
>          <properties>
>             <property>
>                <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
>                <value>${threadcount}</value>
>             </property>
>          </properties>
>       </configuration>    
>    </plugin> 
> </plugins>
> ```
>
> Where dataproviderthreadcount is the default number of threads to use
> for data providers when running tests in parallel.