# Cucumber Tests are not running in parallel (cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin)?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, cucumber-jvm

Cucumber Tests are not running in parallel (cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin)?

If i execute my tests with a runner class, one feature file will execute at a time, however when adding the following plugin to my POM file, no feature files seems to execute?

Even though I have pointed to the correct feature files folder?

**My POM file:**

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pim</groupId>
    <artifactId>PimCucumberFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>PimCucumberFramework</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
            <plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generateRunners</id>
      <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- Mandatory -->
        <!-- List of package names to scan for glue code. -->
        <glue>
          <package>com.example</package>
          <package>com.example.other</package>
        </glue>
        <!-- These are optional, with the default values -->
        <!-- Where to output the generated tests -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
        <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
        <featuresDirectory>src/test/java/resources/features</featuresDirectory>
        <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
        <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
        <!-- List of cucumber plugins. When none are provided the json formatter is used. For more 
             advanced usage see section about configuring cucumber plugins -->
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <name>json</name>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <name>com.example.CustomHtmlFormatter</name>
              <extension>html</extension>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
        <strict>true</strict>
        <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
        <monochrome>true</monochrome>
        <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property. Default is no tags. -->
        <tags>
          <tag>@important</tag>
        </tags>
        <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of JUnit ones. --> 
        <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
        <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' --> 
        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
        <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
        <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
        <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
        <parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>
        <!-- Specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a path relative to the project base directory) -->
        <customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>
        <!-- Specify a custom package name for generated sources. Default is no package.-->
        <packageName>com.example</packageName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Extent Reports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--PROBLEM https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-spring 
            <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2.5</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
            <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Project structure:**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute cucumber feature file parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034116/how-to-execute-cucumber-feature-file-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
        <groupId>com.pim</groupId> 
        <artifactId>PimCucumberFramework</artifactId> 
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>    
       <packaging>jar</packaging>   
       <name>PimCucumberFramework</name> 
       <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> 
       <properties>     
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> </properties>
       <build> 

     <plugins>
      <plugin> <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId> <version>4.1.0</version>
         <executions> 
              <execution> 
                 <id>generateRunners</id>           
                 <phase>generate-test-sources</phase> 
                 <goals> 
                      <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                 </goals> 
                 <configuration> 
                 <!-- Mandatory --> 
                 <!-- List of package names to scan for glue code. --> 
                 <glue>
                      <package>stepDefinitions</package> 
                </glue>
                <!-- These are optional, with the default values --> 
                <!-- Where to output the generated tests --> 
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>         
                  <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files. -->     
                  <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features</featuresDirectory>  
                  <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written -->    
                 <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                 <!-- List of cucumber plugins. When none are provided the json formatter is used. For more advanced usage see section about configuring cucumber plugins -->
                 <plugins>
                    <plugin> 
                        <name>json</name> 
                    </plugin> 
                </plugins>
                <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property --> <strict>true</strict> 
               <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
               <monochrome>true</monochrome> 
              <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property. Default is no tags. -->
             <tags>
                  <tag>~@important</tag> 
            </tags> 
            <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of JUnit ones. -->
            <useTestNG>false</useTestNG> 
            <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes. One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' -->    
            <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme> 
            <!-- The class naming pattern to use. Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.--> 
            <namingPattern>Parallel{c}Test</namingPattern> 
            <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario. FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->      
           <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme> 
          </configuration> 
         </execution> 
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugins>
</build> <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> <version>3.4.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> <version>4.12</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> <type>pom</type> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core --> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html --> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId> <version>0.2.3</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java --> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps --> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId> <version>1.0.5</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin --> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId> <version>2.12.2</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all --> <dependency> <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId> <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId> <version>1.3</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer --> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng --> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> </dependency> <!-- Extent Reports --> <dependency> <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId> <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId> <version>3.0.5</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker --> <dependency> <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId> <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId> <version>2.3.26-incubating</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting --> <dependency> <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId> <version>3.6.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId> <version>2.0.4</version> </dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps --> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId> <version>1.0.5</version> </dependency> <!--PROBLEM https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-spring <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version> </dependency> --> </dependencies> </project>
```

Comment: Updated the features path. try and let me know. I have same kinds of setup and it is working fine for me.

Comment: thanks again for your help, where abouts do i add the listed code inside my POM file, do i also need to remove the surefire configuration which points to the TestNG xml?

Comment: thanks, i have added the code as a plugin inside the POM file but dosnt seem to execute the feature files

Comment: would you be able to show me the location within the above POM file?

Comment: I have pasted entire pom file contents in answer. You can try now.

Comment: thanks again im afraid the attached code still contain exceptions

Comment: @Murthi Multiple tags are not working in Cucumber JVM Plugin but it works for single tag.
How to make it work with multiple tags