# How to run Cucumber features Parallel using TESTNG .

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

i am using this Suite runner class

```
@CucumberOptions(
monochrome=true,
features="src/test/java/com/zopa/testcases",
plugin={"pretty","html:target/cucumber-html-report",
        "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:ExtentReports/ExtentReports.html" },
         glue="com/company/testcases/")
public class SuiteRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() {

    }
```

And This is my Testng.xml file

```
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.company.runner.SuiteRunner"></class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Not sure where to add parallel execution in the cucumber using TestNG.

Comment: https://opencredo.com/test-automation-concepts-parallel-test-execution/ Some details you should take care off

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute cucumber feature file parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034116/how-to-execute-cucumber-feature-file-parallel)