# Reports with Cucumber JVM Parallel plugin

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I am new to the Cucumber. Can anyone please help me on how to run Cucumber with parallel execution and at the same time have thread safe reports?

I am able to run Cucumber with `JVM parallel plugin` with `surefire`, but the problem is I'm not getting thread safe reports (meaning: I was having extent reports and ExtendedCucumberOptions Report but it does not generate after I run the execution with Parallel plugin).

All my requirement are if someone can guide (GitHub link) with me which is best method to achieve the following:

```
- BDD with Cucumber
- Headless Mode(Chrome Headless)
- Parallel Execution
- Thread safe Reports with screenshots (Success/Failure).
```

Just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: For parallel you need to use the @RunWith(ExtendedParallelCucumber.class). http://mkolisnyk.github.io/cucumber-reports/parallel-runner

Comment: Yes it is possible See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034116/how-to-execute-cucumber-feature-file-parallel