# Running a single test suite multiple times in parallel with Serenity

Tags: testing, junit, cucumber, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I have a single test suite (i.e. feature) written with Java/Appium. I want to run this test suite on several different devices (iPhone, Android phones, etc.). I want to do this in parallel as well - i.e. I want to run the same test suite as several separate threads.

How can I do this using Serenity with either Junit, Cucumber, or JBehave? I have found lots of info on how Cucumber allows multiple features to be run in parallel ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034116/how-to-execute-cucumber-feature-file-parallel/41100104#41100104) and [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)), but the problem is, I want to run one single feature multiple times in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run them in separate jobs on your build server and pass in the device as a parameter?