# Selenium cucumber Java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

My question is about cucumber feature files parallel execution. Is it possible to run multiple cucumber feature files in parallel through one runner class in Selenium Java?

I have tried with different approaches but not succeeded.

Comment: Please add an example of what you tried.

Comment: I have followed the steps given in the  url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034116/how-to-execute-cucumber-feature-file-parallel/41100104    . but still i was not succeed

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Plugin And Maven Dependancy:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration> 
        <forkCount>5</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.class</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Open Source Maven Dependancy:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.temyers/cucumber-                      
    jvm-parallel-plugin -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Maven Surefire Plugin to pom.xml, place it between properties and dependencies, and replace CucksRunner with your runner file name:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M9</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/CukesRunner*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```