# Unable to generate the extent-report

Tags: java, cucumber, extentreports

Using the plugin com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter (the only that worked for me), my report is generated but with several errors on the log of intellij

I've tried to generate the report with a scenario not defined (just for the speed). Using more than one plugin, as the plugin

These are the depencies I'm using:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html")

@AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("path/extent-config.xml"));
}
```

The errors:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (freemarker.cache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.


java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(Ljava/io/File;)V

at com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter.loadXMLConfig(Reporter.java:66)
at test.runner.TestRunner.writeExtentReport(TestRunner.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter.result(ExtentCucumberFormatter.java:252)...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using vimal, avenstack and adapter dependencies all together in pom.xml which is not advisable and expected. One shall use vimal or avenstack or both together in specific use case or use adapter dependency only. Please follow below instructions.

**Vimal Selvam Library:** Below is the required maven dependency and a sample test to demonstrate how configuration set up is done.

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note that **Java 8+** and adding the dependency of **ExtentReport v3.1.1+** is mandatory.

**Cucumber Runner File**

```
 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
            glue = {"com.cucumber.stepdefinitions"},
            plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"}
            )
    public class RunCukesTest {
        @AfterClass
        public static void teardown() {
            Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("src/test/resources/extent-config.xml"));
            Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
            Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "Mac OSX");
            Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Sample test runner output message");
        }
    }
```

The above setup will generate the report in output directory with the name of report.html.

**Please remove adapter dependency from pom.xml.** We shall use vimal/avenstack or extent adapter but not all together.

**Extent Adapter:** Beauty is, you do not need to write any code any where to generate report this way except from setting adapter in runner below.

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the **com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter plugin** to the runner.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"})
public class RunCukesTest {
    // ..
}
```

**Report Output Directory** - ../Project Directory/test-output/HtmlReport

**Additional Note:** In future, we would request you to use Cucumber **v>=4.0.0** as you are using pretty old dependency(**v1.2.5**) of Cucumber.

**For doing so**, you can add below set of cucumber minimal dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I was trying to do correctly what you've said before coming back, and good news: there's no error anymore. I updated my pom.xml with io.cucumber dependencies instead of info.cukes. The **bad news** my report is not been generated: pom just has the cucumber4-adapter, and in the test runner I've needed to add into @BeforeClass the following: `ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        extentReports.setGherkinDialect("pt");` because the language is portuguese. Do I need to call a method to generate the report into an afterclass or something like that?

Comment: Now I've tried to do with **cucumber-extentsreport** and **extentreports** dependencies, deleting the adapter. But also without success :(

Comment: @FelipeLuz - Where u able to resolve issue of extent report not generation. Facing same issue with my project. Please help.

Comment: @Suraj Gupta, please share your pom.xml

Comment: Hi @TheSociety Added the POM. please have a look. I checked your comment on some other posts(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763356/extentreport-support-for-cucumber-jvm-4-0-io-cucumber) as well where u adviced not  to use ExtentAdapter and ExtentReport together. Tried that as well(hence code is commented). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TheSociety Can you be more specific which ExtentReport dependency is mandatory to add for the given line "Please note that Java 8+ and adding the dependency of ExtentReport v3.1.1+ is mandatory". ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuraton>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                    </configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>4.10.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>CucumberWebGui</projectName>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                                <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 
    
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
  

  
   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cucumber.version>4.8.0</cucumber.version>
        <!-- <extentreports.version>5.0.3</extentreports.version> -->
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

       
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.72</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
             <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>klov-reporter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.11</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>4.0.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        
        
        <dependency>
<groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
<version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency> 
        
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>allow-snapshots</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>snapshots-repo</id>
         <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
         <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
         <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>

        <profile>
        
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.8</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                            <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                            <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
  
  <name>WebAutomation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <description>Web Automation Framework</description>
    <organization>
        <name>MidTrans Demo</name>
    </organization>
</project>
```