# How to group and run cucumber selenium tests in parallel on two chrome browser instances on Docker?

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

I want to group my tests based on the cucumber tags, and run them on two separate chrome browser sessions on a Docker, I am able to configure and run with a single session, but want to achieve it on multiple chrome browser sessions.

Comment: which language library you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to configure as per cucumber 4 parallel plug-in `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin`

Source:

[How to execute cucumber feature file parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034116/how-to-execute-cucumber-feature-file-parallel)

OR you need to integrate testng parallel execution

https://www.guru99.com/sessions-parallel-run-and-dependency-in-selenium.html

implement first this in your local and then your use docker selenium grid